# Firebase Realtime Database, setValue() does nothing

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

**Edit: problem solved by moving setValue(newProfile) below createUserWithEmailAndPassword method.**

I am trying to register people and put their information to database using Firebase in the same activity. There is no problem registering them. But even though user is registered, MainActivity starts and then toast message shows up; setValue() under the same method with these commands doesn't write informations to database. Here is writing to database part (**setValue() parameter newProfile is declared as HashMap<>()**):

```
mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
firebaseAuthStateListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
        final FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

        if(user != null){
            databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().
                    child(selected_server).child(user_role).child(user.getUid());
            databaseReference.setValue(newProfile);
            Toast.makeText(Registration.this,"Registration completed!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent intent = new Intent(Registration.this,MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    }
};
```

and  here is the registration part:

```
btn_register.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        final String email = et_email.getText().toString();
        final String password = et_password.getText().toString();

        if(needed_role.equals("") || user_role.equals("") || selected_server.equals("") ) {
            Toast.makeText(Registration.this,"Please complete all informations" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        else{
            mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password).addOnCompleteListener(Registration.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    newProfile.put("E-mail" , et_email.getText().toString());
                    newProfile.put("Password" , et_password.getText().toString());
                    newProfile.put("Server" , selected_server);
                    newProfile.put("Summoner Name",et_summoner_name.getText().toString());
                    newProfile.put("Role", user_role);
                    newProfile.put("Needed" , needed_role);
                    if(!task.isSuccessful()){
                        Toast.makeText(Registration.this,"Sign up error" + task.getException(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: first check your logcat for firebase error, its easier to track the issue that way, secondly please  add `addOnSuccessListener` and `addOnFailureListener` to `setValue` before showing a "Registration completed!" toast and taking user inside

Comment: I added these methods and checked the logcat: Here are the error messages:
`"E/FirebaseInstanceId: Failed to start service while in background: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not allowed to start service Intent { act=com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT pkg=com.google.android.gm cmp=com.google.android.gm/com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdService (has extras) }: app is in background uid UidRecord{f74fa9e u0a62 RCVR idle change:uncached procs:1 seq(0,0,0)}"`

Comment: and second error message is:
`E/FirebaseInstanceId: Failed to start service while in background: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not allowed to start service Intent { act=com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT pkg=com.google.android.gm cmp=com.google.android.gm/com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdService (has extras) }: app is in background uid UidRecord{d068b17 u0a62 LAST idle procs:1 seq(0,0,0)}`

Comment: I dont think they are related to your error, i'll suggest you log `newProfile` content just to confirm it has data, which could be the cause

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `updateChildren`

Make sure you are not using the `hashmap` before putting value into it

```
    final DatabaseReference databaseRef =FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().
                    child(selected_server).child(user_role).child(user.getUid();
                                databaseRef.updateChildren(newProfile)
                                        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {

                                            }
                                        });
```

Comment: Hello. I changed method as updateChildren, at first it worked out but now it doesn't.

Comment: What did you mean? What is the thing you wanted to do again? Hi, can you screenshot your firebase db structure?